# Два фрагмента переключаются между собой ( не должны разрушать) как это сделать?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, dagger2, moxy

Есть 2 фрагмента(буду называть 1 и 2 соответственно), наследуемые от базового класса `BaseFragment`. 1 фрагмент запускается по умолчанию. 2 при выборе пункта меню. Я хочу чтобы при переходе из 1->2 и 2->1 и т д. фрагменты не разрушались, а состояние их призентеров сохранялись. Как это можно сделать?

```
  private void setFragment(BaseFragment fragment) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                .commit();
    }
```

Сделал как выше (один раз создаю и сохраняю каждый фрагмент и вызываю по необходимости), но такой вариант полностью разрушает фрагмент при переходе к следующему через replace. Подскажите решение

Comment: Количество фрагментов будет увеличиваться ?

Comment: Как вариант - добавьте сразу оба контейнера и присваивайте неактивному `visible=gone`

Comment: @GinTasan да, будет

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14347588/show-hide-fragment-in-android